# Using Alembic only scan through one table

Tags: postgresql, alembic

I have multiple databases, I am using alembic to maintain the migrations for these database.

However I am currently using older version of alembic (Version  1.6.5)

I am trying to upgrade to a latest version of alembic as it supports multi-tenancy.

This is what my env.py file looks like

```
from __future__ import with_statement

import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context
from new_models import managedObjects
from new_models import ignoreObjects


# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
logger = logging.getLogger('alembic.env')

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
from flask import current_app
config.set_main_option(
    'sqlalchemy.url',
    str(current_app.extensions['migrate'].db.engine.url).replace('%', '%%'))
target_metadata = current_app.extensions['migrate'].db.metadata
print("target", target_metadata)
# print('printing metadata', target_metadata)

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """

    def include_object(object, name, type_, reflected, compare_to):
        # print('compare to', compare_to)
        # print('object', object)
        # print('type', type_)

        # if hasattr(object, 'schema'):
            # print(object.schema)
        print('_________________')
        print('obj', str(object), '--',  str(object).split('.')[0], '--',  obj)
        if any(((obj == str(object)) | (obj == str(object).split('.')[0])) for obj in managedObjects):
            if any((iobj == str(object)) for iobj in ignoreObjects):
                print('Ignoring Object')
                return False
            # print('including', object.schema)
            print('including')
            return True
        print('not including')
        return False

    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    print("Got here!")
    context.configure(
        include_object=include_object,
        url=url, target_metadata=target_metadata, literal_binds=True
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """

    # this callback is used to prevent an auto-migration from being generated
    # when there are no changes to the schema
    # reference: http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/cookbook.html
    def process_revision_directives(context, revision, directives):
        if getattr(config.cmd_opts, 'autogenerate', False):
            script = directives[0]
            if script.upgrade_ops.is_empty():
                directives[:] = []
                logger.info('No changes in schema detected.')

    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix='sqlalchemy.',
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    def include_object(object, name, type_, reflected, compare_to):
        print('compare to', compare_to)
        print('object', object)
        print('type', type_)
        print("managed objects", managedObjects)
        if hasattr(object, 'schema'):
            print(object.schema)
        print('_________________')
        print('obj', str(object), '|',  str(object).split('.')[0])
        if any(((obj == str(object)) | (obj == str(object).split('.')[0])) for obj in managedObjects):
            if any((iobj == str(object)) for iobj in ignoreObjects):
                print('Ignoring Object')
                return False
            # print('including', object.schema)
            print('including')
            return True
        print('not including')
        return False

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            include_schemas=False,
            # include_object=include_object,
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            process_revision_directives=process_revision_directives,
            **current_app.extensions['migrate'].configure_args
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

When I run the following code it takes forever to complete as it's comparing against every single schema in my DB.

I.e the function `include_object` seems to be comparing against every single schema in my DB.

How can I make it so at least for testing purposes so that alembic doesn't look into every single schema.

I.e

I have a table called 'User', 'Roles'

I want alembic to be only comparing changes against User table only.

as of now it appears to scan against User and Role both tables. My practical example includes tons of other tables, hence running this script takes forever.

The parameter `object` in function `include_object` is what I am referring to. How can I make sure it only does it against User table?